# CCNet live updates to LCD TV

Tags: cruisecontrol.net

I am working on Agile project and we use an automated build which runs on a build server using Cruise Control.Net. We have alse integrated various things like

NUnit test execution

Code coverage using NCover

FxCop for code analysis

StyleCop for source code analysis

We also fail the builds if certain criterieas like acceptable code coverage are not met.

I would like to know if there is any free tool which can be used to display the various outputs of cruise control and reports onto a LCD TV at periodic interval. These outputs should show the near realitime status of the latest build including

Build summary

NUnit test summary

FXCop Summary

StyleCop violation

NCoverCovergae summary report

When I say near real time I mean it should refresh the TV screen every few minutes, may be 10 or 15 minutes. I have various projects running for which I would like to display each of the above mentioned reports.

Any help in this regards will be highly appriciated.

Answer (score 2):

Displaying all the information mentioned above might get pretty confusing. There is a tool that can display the CCNET build status: [Cradiator](http://cradiator.codeplex.com/). Perhaps it suits Your needs.

Comment: I don't want to display all the information in one screen. Currently i am displaying them as slides in a powerpoint presentation by taking a screenshot if fullscreen mode. I was just thinking if there exists something which i can readily use.